# Dropdown Mouse Hover Problems

Tags: css, hover, cursor, styling

I have a style where certain elements have a hover functionality to change the mouse cursor.  When a select drop down is present the mouse cursor still picks up on the elements behind the drop down hover functionality.  Can i block hover functionality of anything behind my select options?

Thank you

Example:

background element:

```
[disabled].form-control, fieldset[disabled] .form-control{
   cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try to exclude it with

```
.parent :not(.your_dropdown):hover {
    hover effect of your other elements
 }
```

but it needs a parent else everything hovers XD

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="your_dropdown"></div>
   <div class="your other hover content"></div>
</div>
```